# Does GridDB Supports Procedural Sql (PL/SQL)?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, griddb

According to GridDB documentation,it supports basic SQL operations such as DDL/DML queries. But there is no info about whether it supports advanced SQL functions or not.

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.griddb.net/sqlreference/sql-commands-supported/

Comment: You mean "But there is **no** info about..."? If so, please edit the question.

Comment: Sorry for the typo edited ..thanks mate